# GCP bucket stream was not opened for writing with openxml sdk c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, openxml-sdk, openxml-powertools

I am struggling with modifying the data in stream which i got from google cloud bucket. Here is the code to get the stream -

```
var storageService = new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                   HttpClientInitializer = googleCredential,
                });
    
                var getRequest = storageService.Objects.Get(bucketName, fileName);
    
                var stream = await getRequest.ExecuteAsStreamAsync();
```

Then i am using openxml sdk to modify this stream with some token replacement and then download a new document in browser.

```
   public static void ReplaceTokens(Stream stream, DocumentTemplateTokenData data)
      {
         try
         {          
            using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
// token replacement in doc

            }
}
catch(exception ex)
{}
```

this is giving me error that stream was not opened to writing. PLease help, already wasted lot of time trying many solutions.

Comment: Anyone has idea? still waiting for solution.